# Newline in Constant when assigning value to string using multiple lines

Tags: c#, sql-server, newline

I am writing C# code i.e. a SQL Server query as follows:

```
query.CommandText = "select keyterm from sub_aminer_author where aid IN (10, 
46,
99,
106,
132,
159,
260,
264,
316,
.
.
.,
25718)
```

It gives me Newline in Constant error......whereas I have fetched these values from an SQL table, then added commas to these values using Excel, Now when I copy these values from Excel and paste into C# query editor, it gives this error. How to handle this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to make it a [string literal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090(v=vs.71).aspx):

```
query.CommandText = @"select keyterm from sub_aminer_author where aid IN (10, 
46,
...,
25718);";
```

Using the `@` at the beginning of your string will count any newlines, spaces, or any other characters as part of the string, until it finds the closing `"`.

*Note: the only downside is that if you use any escape characters (i.e. anything lead by a "`\`") it will negate them and put them into the string as part of the text.